# I want to make my links ease into images

Tags: css

I am a beginner in this and  I am working on my new website. But I am stuck at one point where I want the effect that will make my links fade into images. I am having a navigation-bar on top of my page and when I hover over the link, I want the text to fade out at the same time as a small logo is fading in. And when I hover out of the link I want the image to fade out at the same time as the lin is fading back in, you know?

But when I do this, the image just pops up and fades out at the same time as the link is fading out...

```
#navigation a[name="project"] {
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#navigation a[name="project"]:hover {
opacity:0;
background-image:url(bilder/project.png)
}
```

Comment: Could you add a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) to illustrate what you've done so far?

Comment: Could you please include your HTML in the question and include a link to a jsFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is the background for the element you're fading out, so it will also fade on hover. You'll need to separate the image into a separate element.

Perhaps you could use absolute positioning inside a container to have the text cover up the image, and then when the text is hovered over, it'll fade out, revealing the image underneath.

A working example of this is at http://jsfiddle.net/y9aw7/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#">Example Text</a>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

a, img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

a {
    z-index: 1;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s opacity;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s opacity;
    -o-transition: 0.4s opacity;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s opacity;
    transition: 0.4s opacity;
}

a:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Edit: Further jsfiddle, forked from the fiddle provided by the OP, with corrected CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/JmwdC/1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HdDBk/2/

Here is the code, but of course I will have to include the image links somewhere, but do you see what I am trying to do?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. Here's a working example of my suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/y9aw7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y9aw7/3/

Check this out, I used your method, and it fades like I want, but it is showing both content now and still: both fades out at the same time.

Comment: Hey, wait a minute, this is getting really close now, but still a little tiny bit I don't get, look at it now! http://jsfiddle.net/stAqD/1/

Comment: Look, you know my navigation-bar. It is built up by six links. And for each link, I want a different logo to fade in when I hover over the link. But I don't want it to just pop in there. I want it to fade out the link text, and at the same time fade in the image(the logo). And when i hover away from the link, I want the effect to reverse. 

I am sorry that I am irritating you, but as I said I am a beginner.

Comment: I forked your fiddle to this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JmwdC/1/ Hover over the facebook link and the image will display correctly. If it works, could you accept my answer? Trying to build up some reputation :)

Comment: I just made a user here, sorry but I don't know what is right or wrong here haha. At least I "accepted" your answer!

Comment: Cheers! :) Everybody's new to begin with!

Comment: @surfitscrollit Please refrain from asking people to vote/accept your answers. [See this meta post for more information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167155/152134). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ipinal/1)

CSS

```
#gl{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  opacity:0;
  transition:all 0.5s;  
}
#gl:hover{
  opacity:1;

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href='http://www.google.com/'>  <img id=gl src='https://www.google.co.in/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif'>
 Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is fast and support live preview.

Comment: Do you see where I am trying to go?

Comment: @Snik1 Copying it to JSbin :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use any property you want to achieve this, except `display` which does not work with **CSS3 transition**.

The most common techniques make use of

- opacity (to 0)
- height (to 0)
- z-index (to negative / lower value than the container)

Sticking to your example, you can do it by using an `background-image` in `<li>`, and changing the opacity to the `<a>`, no changes to your HTML are needed.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D6wuH/2/

Relevant CSS

```
li {
    /* ... other stuff... */
    background:none no-repeat scroll center center ;
}

#navigation li,  #navigation li > a{
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;    
}
 #navigation li > a{
    background: white;
 }

#navigation li:hover {
    background:url(http://dareminnesota.com/images/facebook-like-button.png) 
                   no-repeat scroll center center transparent;    
}
#navigation li:hover > a {    
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Playing with the difference between the initial state and the hover state of a lot of properties (was X, on hover becomes Y; wasn't there, on hover it's there; was there, on hover it's not there anymore) will let you achieve a world of different results, with weird effects like this: http://jsfiddle.net/D6wuH/0/ :)

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you so much! 

Could you tell what is wrong here? I want to line up everything and get an logo for each, but it all just floats to the left and only facebook is shown and twitter when I hover over... http://jsfiddle.net/stAqD/2/

Comment: Remove all your absolute positions :)

Comment: +1 for showing there are multiple solutions for the same problem with HTML and CSS (I love that about it!)